# the props change when the state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

i have `usersList` array comes from api request

1. i handle the data coming from api with `react-redux`, and then i store the `usersList` coming from api in my `state` in `getDerivedStateFromProps`

```
  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    const newState = {};
    if(state.usersList !== props.usersList && props.usersList.length > 0 && props.loadingStep === '3'){
      newState.usersList = props.usersList;
    }
    return newState;
  }
```

2. i display the content of `usersList` array in the `render` function, the user may edit the information or may not.
3. when the user edit the information i save the new info in `this.state`

```
this.setState({ usersList:newList }); // where the newList contain the new info
```

**The problem**

the problem is when the user may want to undo that change.
so i suppose to update the state with the old information in `this.props.usersList`

but i find the `this.props.usersList` contain the same info that in the state

```
console.log(this.state.usersList) // [1,2,3, ... the new info]
console.log(this.props.usersList) // [1,2,3, ... the new info]
```

my question is :

why `this.props.usersList` updated with the update of `this.state.usersList`

Comment: How do you call `getDerivedStateFromProps`? And how do you create newList before `this.setState({ usersList:newList });`?

Comment: You are probably mutating this.state.userList, this.props.userList or both but we can't see where `the new info` comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newState.usersList = props.usersList;`

Creates a reference to props.usersList. Therefore it will always refer to the usersList.

Try to clone the array of `props.usersList`:

```
newState.usersList = [...props.usersList];
```

With the spread operator "..." you can easily clone an array into a new one without being only a reference.

Does that help?

Comment: The only way that changing this.state.userList modifies this.props.userList is by mutation so we need to know how the OP gets to mutate.